# How to put a multi-lines text in a database from the command line?

Tags: command-line, database

I have emails exports in full text (one file per email). I want to put them in a database from a shell script (bash or python). Let's say I have created a database with a emails table, and from, to, cc, bcc, object, date, body and some custom columns, and let's say I am using mariadb or preferably a full text database. How can I write a command to write the body of the message in the body cell of the database ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to import the text files from within MariaDB itself. You can use either `mysqlimport [OPTIONS] database textfile ...` or `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE tbl_name ...` for this purpose.

References: [mysqlimport](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlimport/) and [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/load-data-infile/)